# Intento crear una funcion f(x) y parsearla a doble

Tags: java

Escribi estos 2 metodos que parsean String a doble, pero solo me funcionan con un a+b, 5+5,4-4,5*5,etc; lo que quiero hacer es que no lo hagan con solo a+b, si no que sea un a+b+c+d+e-f-g*f..etc; y no tengo ni idea de como meter la funcion String a un bucle para que recorra siempre si hay otro operador matematico ahi... alguien ayuda?

```
public void Leer() {
    System.out.println("Escribe una funcion:");
    funcion = sms.nextLine();
    tamaño = funcion.length();
    funcionDe = new double[tamaño];
    funcionDe2 = new double[tamaño];
    matriz = new String[tamaño];
}

   public void Parsear(String funcion) {
    funcion = this.funcion;
    for (int i = 0; i < tamaño; i++) {
        matriz[i] = funcion.substring(i, i + 1);
        //System.out.println(matriz[i]);
        switch (matriz[i]) {
            case "+":
                System.out.println("Hay una suma");
                funcionDe[i] = Double.parseDouble(funcion.substring(0, i));
                funcionDe2[i] = Double.parseDouble(funcion.substring(i + 1, (tamaño)));
                System.out.println(matriz.length);
                System.out.println(funcionDe[i] + funcionDe2[i]);
                break;

            case "-":
                System.out.println("Hay una suma");
                funcionDe[i] = Double.parseDouble(funcion.substring(0, i));
                funcionDe2[i] = Double.parseDouble(funcion.substring(i + 1, (tamaño)));
                System.out.println(matriz.length);
                System.out.println(funcionDe[i] - funcionDe2[i]);
                break;

            case "*":
                funcionDe[i] = Double.parseDouble(funcion.substring(0, i));
                funcionDe2[i] = Double.parseDouble(funcion.substring(i + 1, (tamaño)));
                System.out.println(matriz.length);
                System.out.println(funcionDe[i] * funcionDe2[i]);
                break;

            case "/":
                funcionDe[i] = Double.parseDouble(funcion.substring(0, i));
                funcionDe2[i] = Double.parseDouble(funcion.substring(i + 1, (tamaño)));
                System.out.println(matriz.length);
                System.out.println(funcionDe[i] / funcionDe2[i]);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usas `double`: ¿Significa eso que los números pueden tener decimales? Si es así ¿usas la coma, el punto o ambos para separar las cifras enteras de los decimales?

Comment: @PabloLozano como es un String uso el punto

Answer (score 1):

## Introducción

Según veo en tu código lo que intentas realizar es un interprete de expresiones aritméticas y las operaciones que manejarás son suma, resta, multiplicación y división.

Al involucrar más operaciones de suma y resta la solución se volverá más compleja dado que necesitarás considerar la [jerarquía de operaciones](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orden_de_evaluaci%C3%B3n).

---

### Solución

Mi propuesta está en la teoría para crear [interpretes de lenguajes de programación](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)), ya que estos son capaces de realizar estás operaciones básicas y también funcionan sobre otro lenguaje de programación base.

---

### Justificación

La característica que nos interesa sobre los intérpretes es el [AST (Abstract Syntax Tree)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), el cuál nos permitirá organizar el order de las operaciones en nuestra expresión e incluso cambiar el orden de estás al usar paréntesis.

---

### Código

Para realizar el intérprete de expresiones aritméticas necesitaremos los siguientes componentes:

- [Lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) (Lexical Analysis).
- [Parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)
- Interpreter
- Interfaz de ejecución (Nuestra CLI app para ingresar la expresión).

#### Lexer

El lexer se encargará de entender los elementos de nuestra expresión. Los elementos pueden ser números enteros o flotantes o también signos de operaciones aritméticas. El objetivo del lexer será arrojarnos una lista con los elementos tokenizados (La referencia de token se puede encontrar en la definición de Lexer).

Aquí el código de Token (Se usa dentro del Lexer):

```java
/**
 * Token is a representation of each component into the
 * expression.
 */
public class Token {
    enum TYPES {
        INT("INT"),
        FLOAT("FLOAT"),
        PLUS("PLUS"),
        MINUS("MINUS"),
        MULTIPLICATION("MULTIPLICATION"),
        DIVISION("DIVISION"),
        LEFTPARENTHESES("LEFT PARENTHESES"),
        RIGHTPARENTHESES("RIGHT PARENTHESES");

        public final String value;

        TYPES(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.value;
        }
    }

    public final TYPES type;
    public final String value;

    public Token(TYPES type, String value) {
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String representation = this.type.toString();
        if (this.type == TYPES.FLOAT || this.type == TYPES.INT) {
            representation += ":" + this.value;
        }
        return representation;
    }
}
```

Código del Lexer:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Lexer {
    private final String text;
    private int position;
    private char currentChar;

    public Lexer(String expression) {
        this.text = expression;
        this.position = -1;
        this.next();
    }

    private void next() {
        this.position++;
        if (this.position < this.text.length()) {
            this.currentChar = this.text.charAt(this.position);
        } else {
            this.currentChar = Character.MIN_VALUE;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Token> makeTokens() {
        ArrayList<Token> tokens = new ArrayList<>();

        while (this.currentChar != Character.MIN_VALUE) {
            if (Character.isDigit(this.currentChar)) {
                tokens.add(this.makeNumber());
            } else if (this.currentChar == '+') {
                tokens.add(new Token(Token.TYPES.PLUS, Character.toString(this.currentChar)));
                this.next();
            } else if (this.currentChar == '-') {
                tokens.add(new Token(Token.TYPES.MINUS, Character.toString(this.currentChar)));
                this.next();
            } else if (this.currentChar == '*') {
                tokens.add(new Token(Token.TYPES.MULTIPLICATION, Character.toString(this.currentChar)));
                this.next();
            } else if (this.currentChar == '/') {
                tokens.add(new Token(Token.TYPES.DIVISION, Character.toString(this.currentChar)));
                this.next();
            } else if (this.currentChar == '(') {
                tokens.add(new Token(Token.TYPES.LEFTPARENTHESES, Character.toString(this.currentChar)));
                this.next();
            } else if (this.currentChar == ')') {
                tokens.add(new Token(Token.TYPES.RIGHTPARENTHESES, Character.toString(this.currentChar)));
                this.next();
            } else if (this.currentChar == ' ' || this.currentChar == '\t') {
                this.next();
            } else {
                throw new Error("Unexpected character at position " + this.position);
            }
        }
        return tokens;
    }

    private Token makeNumber() {
        String tokenStr = "";
        int dotCount = 0;
        while (Character.isDigit(this.currentChar) || this.currentChar == '.') {
            tokenStr += this.currentChar;
            if (this.currentChar == '.') {
                dotCount++;
                if (dotCount > 1) {
                    throw new Error("Unexpected character at position " + this.position);
                }
            }
            this.next();
        }
        Token.TYPES type;
        if (dotCount == 0) {
            type = Token.TYPES.INT;
        } else {
            type = Token.TYPES.FLOAT;
        }
        return new Token(type, tokenStr);
    }
}
```

#### Parser

La función del `parser` es tomar la lista de tokens creada por el lexer para construir el AST. Dentro de nuestro AST tendrémos nodos que representará operaciones binarias, operaciones unitarias y números.

Código de los nodos:

```java
public class BinaryOperationNode {
    public final Object left;
    public final Token operation;
    public final Object right;

    public BinaryOperationNode(Object left, Token operation, Object right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.operation = operation;
        this.right = right;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + this.left.toString() + " " + this.operation.toString() + " " + this.right.toString() + ")";
    }
}

public class UnaryOperationNode {

    public final Token operation;
    public final Object node;

    public UnaryOperationNode(Token operation, Object node) {
        this.operation = operation;
        this.node = node;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String representation = "(";
        if (operation.type == Token.TYPES.MINUS) {
            representation += "-";
        }
        representation += this.node.toString();
        representation += ")";
        return representation;
    }
}


public class NumberNode {
    public final Token token;

    public NumberNode(Token token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.token.toString();
    }
}
```

Código del parser:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Parser {
    private final ArrayList<Token> tokens;
    private int position;
    private Token currentToken;

    public Parser(ArrayList<Token> tokens) {
        this.tokens = tokens;
        this.position = -1;
        this.next();
    }

    private void next() {
        this.position++;
        if (this.position < this.tokens.size()) {
            this.currentToken = this.tokens.get(this.position);
        } else {
            this.currentToken = null;
        }
    }

    public Object makeAbstractSyntaxTree() {
        return this.expression();
    }

    private Object factor() {
        Token token = this.currentToken;
        if (token.type == Token.TYPES.PLUS || token.type == Token.TYPES.MINUS) {
            this.next();
            Object factor = this.factor();
            return new UnaryOperationNode(token, factor);
        } else if (token.type == Token.TYPES.INT || token.type == Token.TYPES.FLOAT) {
            this.next();
            return new NumberNode(token);
        } else if (token.type == Token.TYPES.LEFTPARENTHESES) {
            this.next();
            Object expression = this.expression();
            if (this.currentToken.type == Token.TYPES.RIGHTPARENTHESES) {
                this.next();
                return expression;
            } else {
                throw new Error("Expected ')' but got <" + this.currentToken.type.toString() + ">");
            }
        }
        throw new Error("Expected '+', '-', '(', a float or an integer value but got <" + this.currentToken.type.toString() + ">");
    }

    private Object term() {
        Object left = this.factor();
        while (this.currentToken != null && (this.currentToken.type == Token.TYPES.MULTIPLICATION || this.currentToken.type == Token.TYPES.DIVISION)) {
            Token operation = this.currentToken;
            this.next();
            Object right = this.factor();
            left = new BinaryOperationNode(left, operation, right);
        }
        return left;
    }

    private Object expression() {
        Object left = this.term();
        while (this.currentToken != null && (this.currentToken.type == Token.TYPES.PLUS || this.currentToken.type == Token.TYPES.MINUS)) {
            Token operation = this.currentToken;
            this.next();
            Object right = this.term();
            left = new BinaryOperationNode(left, operation, right);
        }
        return left;
    }
}
```

#### Interpreter

La función del `interpreter` será evaluar el AST y realizar las operaciones aritméticas para devolver un solo resultado.

Código de `NumberValue` (Utilizado para abstraer la representación de un número y sus operaciones):

```java
public class NumberValue {
    public final float value;

    public NumberValue(int value) {
        this.value = (float) value;
    }

    public NumberValue(float value) {
        this.value = (float) value;
    }

    public NumberValue(String value) {
        this.value = Float.parseFloat(value);
    }

    public NumberValue addition(NumberValue addend) {
        return new NumberValue(this.value + addend.value);
    }

    public NumberValue subtraction(NumberValue subtrahend) {
        return new NumberValue(this.value - subtrahend.value);
    }

    public NumberValue division(NumberValue divisor) {
        return new NumberValue(this.value / divisor.value);
    }

    public NumberValue multiplication(NumberValue factor) {
        return new NumberValue(this.value * factor.value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Float.toString(this.value);
    }
}
```

Código del interpreter:

```java
public class Interpreter {
    public Object abstractSyntaxTree;

    public Interpreter(Object abstractSyntaxTree) {
        this.abstractSyntaxTree = abstractSyntaxTree;
    }

    public NumberValue execute() {
        return this.evaluate(this.abstractSyntaxTree);
    }

    public NumberValue evaluate(Object node) {
        String mainObjectClassName = node.getClass().getSimpleName();
        return switch (mainObjectClassName) {
            case "UnaryOperationNode" -> this.unaryOperation((UnaryOperationNode) node);
            case "NumberNode" -> this.number((NumberNode) node);
            case "BinaryOperationNode" -> this.binaryOperation((BinaryOperationNode) node);
            default -> throw new Error("Unsupported node");
        };
    }

    private NumberValue binaryOperation(BinaryOperationNode node) {
        NumberValue left = this.evaluate(node.left);
        NumberValue right = this.evaluate(node.right);

        return switch (node.operation.type) {
            case PLUS -> left.addition(right);
            case MINUS -> left.subtraction(right);
            case MULTIPLICATION -> left.multiplication(right);
            case DIVISION -> left.division(right);
            default -> throw new Error("Unsupported operation type <" + node.operation.type + ">");
        };
    }

    private NumberValue number(NumberNode node) {
        return new NumberValue(node.token.value);
    }

    private NumberValue unaryOperation(UnaryOperationNode node) {
        NumberValue value = this.evaluate(node.node);
        return switch (node.operation.type) {
            case PLUS -> value;
            case MINUS -> value.multiplication(new NumberValue(-1));
            default -> throw new Error("Unsupported operation type <" + node.operation.type + ">");
        };
    }
}
```

#### Aplicación de prueba

Esta será nuestra interfaz para ingresar las expresiones a través de consola. El objetivo de esta aplicación es mostrar la implementación de los componentes anteriores.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Shell {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type an arithmetic expression and press <enter>");
        System.out.print("> ");

        String expression = in.nextLine();
        in.close();

        Lexer lexer = new Lexer(expression);
        ArrayList<Token> tokens = lexer.makeTokens();

        Parser parser = new Parser(tokens);
        Object ast = parser.makeAbstractSyntaxTree();

        Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter(ast);
        NumberValue result = interpreter.execute();

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

---

Puedes ver el código también en github: [repositorio](https://github.com/JoseNoriegaa/simple-arithmetic-expression-interpreter)

> PD: Es el primer desarrollo que hago en Java, probablemente no tenga las mejoras prácticas de código.